# Ответ не является правильным?

Tags: обсуждение

Как поступать в таком случае если решением является перезагрузка компьютера. Знал бы, так и сделал сразу, чаще всего таких решений на маке не возникает. Указал это как ответ.  Оказывается я не прав, оставив такой ответ? Что вы думаете на этот счет? [Ссылка на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558787/os-x-10-11-6-el-capitan-sslread-return-error-9841/558803#558803)

Comment: Минус не обязательно означает, что вы неправы.

Comment: Минусование ответов -- дело добровольное, ну не понравился человеку ответ (на всех не угодишь), каждый поступает так, как ему хочется (вот и Вы не пытайтесь подстраиваться под других, делайте, как сами считаете правильно).

Comment: Да и один минус это не показатель ничего.

Comment: @Nofate сейчас там три минуса и два плюса. Status update :)

Comment: @D-side Квантовый эффект: факт наблюдения повлиял на результат. Не было бы поста, не было бы и минусов.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Ваш ответ не достоин тревоги "не ответ" и её последствий. Минусов — возможно.**

Обсуждаемое сообщение пишет почти прямо "перезагрузился — заработало". В нём возможно не напрямую, но содержится ответ: *"перезагрузитесь, может заработать"*.

Решения, к сожалению, иногда приходится принимать как данность, за неимением внутренних деталей о проблеме или опыта в области проблемы. И даже в таком "голом" виде решение имеет ценность, т. к. помогает устранить проблему.

Мне [приходилось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543045/181100) оставлять решения, которые непонятно почему, но работают, и хотя я осознаю, что это плохо (могут быть *спрятанные неприятные последствия*), **полное отсутствие решения обычно ещё хуже**.

Тут приходится гадать, может ли описанное в ответе действие неявно нанести вред. Перезагрузка, по-моему, достаточно безобидное действие. Для сервера она может быть нежелательной, но администратор сервера обычно знает это наверняка.

---

1. Правильность ответа (галочку) определяете вы сами, как автор вопроса, по одному вам известным собственным соображениям и причинам. "Я сделал это, теперь работает" это достаточная причина. **Вы имеете право поставить галку куда хотите. Это ваш вопрос.**
2. Сообщество (в лице голосов) оценит ваш ответ на качество: достоверность, содержательность, правильность. Вердикт сообщества выражается в голосах отдельных участников. **Каждый участник имеет право распоряжаться голосами как хочет.**

   - ...почти. Исключение это серийные голосования, в которых обычно голоса оценивают не сообщения, а их автора. Это использование голосов не по назначению. Ответственности за это, насколько мне известно, нет, подозрительные голоса (например, сразу пачка в одном направлении) просто исчезнут.
3. **Тревоги предназначены для упрочения использования вещей по назначению**. В частности, ответы должны быть ответами, если они хотя бы пытаются ответить на вопрос. *Тревоги не предназначены для привлечения внимания к неправильным или плохим ответам.*

   - Ими борются в основном с ответами, которые даже не пытаются отвечать на вопросы, т. е. их авторы изначально не ставили себе такую цель. Часто авторы таких ответов **думают, что StackOverflow это форум (а это не так)** и (ошибочно) воспринимают форму "ответа" как "новое сообщение в топик". Содержание таких "ответов" разнится: вопросы, благодарности, подробности, другие обстоятельства той же проблемы — в общем, не решения.